# Using tenses in a text about a deceased person

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Can anyone who has good knowledge in the language please correct my writing. I have problems choosing the correct tense in the following context.

> Bollywood is a one big happy family. And the death of legendary actor Sridevi has shocked the family. The untimely death of the legendary actress, Sridevi due to major cardiac arrest last night has left the country in shock.
>
> The actress started her career in a mere age of 4 and since then she **has/had** ruled millions. She **has given/gave** us many brilliant and memorable performances throughout her career. Movies like Mr.India, English Vinglish, Lamhe, Chaalbaaz etc. have seen the most memorable performances by the actress. The actress **is/was** an epitome of acting, brilliance and perfection.

Comment: Please read the [help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) regarding what kinds of questions are acceptable here. This site doesn't do proofreading. Questions that are acceptable will be about a specific problem that you are having **after** you have done some research yourself and still have difficulties. You might want to do a search here looking for answers that deal with tenses, Past Perfect vs. Present Perfect etc.

Comment: I think that this question is acceptable. He never asked for proof reading, he asked only for help with fixing the verb tenses. I think the way he phrased "please correct my writing" makes it sound like proofreading, but the question is very specific in nature.

Answer (score 1):

The actress started her career in a mere age of 4 and since then she **has** ruled millions. She has **given** us many brilliant and memorable performances throughout her career. Movies like Mr.India, English Vinglish, Lamhe, Chaalbaaz etc. have seen the most memorable performances by the actress. The actress **was** an epitome of acting, brilliance and perfection.

Here's the correct verb tense to use from what I can understand from the context. In the future, you may want to just give the sentences so it's not confused as being a proof reading question.

Comment: why not gave  she is dead now  she won't give any performances

Comment: Having had to talk about a recently deceased person, I found the best approach was to mix both present tense and past tense. This was a style choice, to try to put emphasis on both (1) the person is gone, so use past tense and (2) the person is still with us in our lives, so use present tense.